# Concurrent DateTime + duration SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this data into a table in my DB:

```
StartTime                 Duration
-----------------------------------------    
2014-08-03 08:32:47.987      1
2014-08-03 08:32:59.017      1
2014-08-03 08:36:55.673     12
2014-08-03 08:36:58.067      8
2014-08-03 08:37:36.807     10
```

In my case, the `StartTime` is the start time of the call.

`Duration` is call duration (in seconds).

I need to sort out the number of concurrent calls during a day in a query, I can do it in PHP script but it takes time to execute.

Comment: Define your tolerance for what constitutes "concurrent"?  Within a second, or a tenth, hundredth, or exact millisecond?

Comment: the easiest way to determine concurrent calls would be to set an end date when a call completes - every call without an end date is currently 'active'.

Comment: @Kritner You are alright, the end date will be the StartTime + Duration, then compare it with other rows.

Comment: I guess reading again I'm going to guess that you want to plug in a specific datetime and determine how many calls were active at that time?  Again, an enddate time would make things easiest, but you could do something gross like generate an endtime based on a `dateadd(s, startTime, duration)` per row - but this could be very non-performant depending on the size of the table and indexes, and the nature of what you're hoping to accomplish

Comment: @WilliamPrice i want it in seconds, not millisecond.

Comment: Actually there will be more than 1000 records, so i dont know if i generate new column then the query takes time to execute.

Comment: I would consider adding a computed column so you don't have to calculate the EndTime all the time. And if there is only 1,000 rows in this table then just about anything (except RBAR) will be fast.

Comment: You are effectively looking for islands of contiguous dates. Check out this article. It is a great way to deal with this kind of thing. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/

Comment: Why are you storing the duration instead of the end time? I would rather store the end time. You can always calculate the duration if you need it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it's the Table structure ...

Comment: Yes, but tables are not etched into stone tablets. You can always consider improving them to store the information that matters rather than the information that seemed to matter to the original designer.

Comment: Yes you are right dear, but we are using many duration values in our table, call duration, Waiting in IVR duration etc...

Comment: What does "get the concurrent calls during this day" mean?  Are you looking for a maximum number of concurrent calls for the day? (a single data point) As @WilliamPrice asked, are you looking for a more of a line plot of data say per minute with a maximum number of concurrent calls for that minute?  You need to describe what you want your returned data to look like and potentially provide samples, as right now there is not enough information to provide an answer without a lot of guesswork on the answerers end.

Comment: Yes @Kritner this is what i need actually (max nummber of concurrent calls for the day)

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways. You can do a query like this:

```
SELECT pointintime, increment
FROM
(
    SELECT StartTime AS pointintime, 1 AS increment
    FROM yourtable
    --add eventually where filter here
    UNION ALL
    DATEADD(second, Duration, StartTime) AS pointintime, -1 AS increment
    FROM yourtable
    --add eventually where filter here
) AS a
ORDER BY pointintime
```

And then, via PHP, you can fast count how many calls are in any moment (working on the increment column), do pretty reports and so on.

Second way, do the same query, but using a cursor. I don't like cursors.

Way 3: prepare your data. I mean, store these informations in a separate table. You can also track changes in real time to have data ready to extract. But before write some code for this, we need to know if you can use triggers, if you use an insert and then an update, or if you insert record once completed the call. Also it is important to know if this data can be updated... This is my favourite way: it will faster. You can also prepare data once a day with a job and so on. But also way number 1 can work, with few code on php side.